# Is websocket connectivity as default maintained without polling in mobile?

Tags: browser, websocket, reverse-proxy, long-polling

As per the theory, A websocket was introduced to avoid polling and avoid HTTP header overheads for each requests. Therefore single connection and bi-directional messages without polling latencies can be achieved with websocket.

My questions are.

1.) If I am programming a native mobile application (Android/IOS) using 3rd party library to establish websocket connectivity (without using browser). Will the connection is maintained similar to the browser websocket?

2.) If the mobile does not maintain the websocket connection then should I drop the idea of websocket and go back to HTTP polling mechanism or websocket polling?

3.) Is mobile operating systems really supports websocket to maintain connection without polling?

4.) Is websocket is only designed for PC browser based JavaScript applications and non-mobile applications?

5.) What technique actually the browser uses to maintain a websocket connectivity, is the browser is sending ping-pong heartbeat internally?

6.) Is websocket is inefficient/almost-not-possible when it is proxied with reverse proxy technique or URL rewriting techniques (Say NGINX)?

Answer (score 3):

You might find the [following answer about websockets helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974884/is-websocket-is-dedicated-for-browsers-only/30991894#30991894).

In general, the websocket should be maintained by the third-party library the same way it is maintained by the browser.

Websocket is a protocol that runs over TCP/IP and can be used without a browser.

This also means that the same limitations apply as with every TCP/IP connection - these are the same limitations as with a web browser.

For instance, the connection will be closed if the application loses focus (closed or put in background). This is part the mobile OS's imposed limitations and it's probably designed this way to save battery life (for instance, iOS will close any active connections to save battery)... Depending on the library, it could be your responsibility to re-establish the Wobsocket connection after it was closed.

**ALSO *REMEMBER***: most mobile OS's (such as iOS) allow your app to register for a push notifications service - [here is Apple's info about the service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html). For the most part, this is the best system that will allow you to push data to your app even while the app is closed.

so, to answer your questions:

1. Yes, the connection is maintained similarly to a browser's websocket - with the same limitations and assuming the third party's library is mature enough.
2. HTTP pulling will probably burn more resources than websockets. Because websockets are possible, it is better to use Websockets... But, unless you are using live data (such as stocks, sports, gaming, etc'), the **Push notifications system** is probably your best friend.
3. Yes. A normal websocket library will maintain the websocket without pulling, using IO signals from the OS.
4. No. Websocket is a protocol that actually helps bypass a lot of firewall and proxy issues by 'piggy-backing' over HTTP connections. It could be (and is) used by non-PC and non-Browser platforms and apps, as well as on mobile devices.

   (I know, for a fact, that some games use websockets on their mobile platforms for live gaming)
5. The browser doesn't normally send ping-pong websocket frames. This is the job of the server application. Some frameworks (for example, [The Plezi Ruby web-app framework](http://boazsegev.github.io/plezi/) ) manage the ping-pong automatically. Other frameworks require that you do it... but it's almost always a server-side decision (javascript ping-pings aren't even available on most browsers).

Good Luck!

**EDIT**

You asked another question in the comment - your connection closes after 1 minute and you asked who is closing it.

The answer is that the server is automatically closing websocket connections, usually if they are inactive for some time.

For instance, Heroku automatically closes websocket connections after [55 seconds](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#timeouts) of inactivity, as noted in [Heroku's websocket documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websockets):

> The normal Heroku HTTP routing timeout rules apply to WebSocket connections. Either client or server can prevent the connection from idling by sending an occasional ping packet over the connection.

This is true for all websocket clients - browsers and native apps. The solution is to find a friendly hosting server and to have the server-side application send pings every 45-50 seconds or so.

This behavior is actually part of the Websocket and HTTP standards and should be considered normal. The [Websocket RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7.2.2) states:

> Servers MAY close the WebSocket connection whenever desired.  Clients SHOULD NOT close the WebSocket connection arbitrarily.  In either case, an endpoint initiates a closure by following the procedures to *Start the WebSocket Closing Handshake* (Section 7.1.2).

Comment: Thanks, yes, I am already using push notifications by sending a flag to my server when the app goes background, But as I am using a 3rd party openfire plugin..... my websocket is automatically closed by 1 minute regardless of app background/foreground state.... therefore I want to confirm who is closing it.

Comment: Hi @ZigmaEmpire, you're welcome. I updated the answer to answer the disconnection. The server is the one that automatically disconnects the websocket.